# Had Apollo astronauts practiced getting up from a fall?

Tags: apollo-program, astronauts, eva, training

The question "[Could an Apollo astronaut stand up if they fell on the moon?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/31545/26446)" describes several incidents of Apollo astronauts falling over while on the moon, and their attempts to get back up.

Did the astronauts practice for this contingency in advance, and what did such training entail?

---

**Edit:** The question is specific to getting up *in an EVA spacesuit*.

Comment: during parabolic flights, IIRC

Comment: A lot of lunar  EVA training was performed on KC-135 flying reduced gravity parabolic flights e.g. https://images.nasa.gov/details-S72-50269.html - I can't remember where I got the notion getting up was part of that training, but even if it wasn't planned,  it probably happened inadvertently

Comment: It might be worth looking into the underwater training that was done by some of the astronauts. Some Apollo [training pictures](https://www.wired.com/2011/07/moon-landing-gallery/) published by Wired magazine.